# Overflowing values in excel

Tags: excel

I am creating my own timesheet for my new business and need help. one cell calculates the hours worked (e.g., G12) and another cell that calculates the overtime worked (e.g., H12) I need a formula that when the hours worked cell is >12 the remainder of the hours worked goes into the overtime cell.
Can you help??

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the following formulas

In my example `A2:A5` has hours of 5 each, for a total of 15 hours

B2 adds up the hours, up to and including 12

C2 shows any hours over 12

B2: `=IF(SUM(A2:A5) <= 12, SUM(A2:A5), 12)`

C2: `=IF(SUM(A2:A5) > 12, SUM(A2:A5) - 12, 0)`

```
  | A     | B     | C        |
--+-------+-------+----------+
1 | Hours | Total | Overtime |
--+-------+-------+----------+
2 | 5     | 12    | 3        |
--+-------+-------+----------+
3 | 5     |       |          |
--+-------+-------+----------+
4 | 5     |       |          |
--+-------+-------+----------+
```